# How does one split the train,cross validation and test set cleanly in python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wanted to split data in three parts, train, cross validation and test set cleanly in python. The [following documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) gives a easy way to do the split between two, test and train. However, to split it say in 40 25 35 I'd need to do the final split myself (using the same function) and do calculations myself to make sure the split is exactly as I want. Is there not a built in that does the split easily without me having to handle the percentage division for the second split?

Comment: two calls to splitting function is not really "doing calculations on your own". Plus doing it this way is better from mathematical perspective, as your 3-part split is actually a simulation of 2 level 2-part split (which you are supposed to implement by calling split twice).

Comment: @lejlot I obviously disagree otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: Sure, I am just telling you why scikit-learn does not support it, and this is the exact reason.